# Can't Insert New Table Row With a Data From the Parameter of a Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here is the error :

> function_script_cashier.js:108 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
>           at AddMenuOnTable (function_script_cashier.js:108)
>           at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (cashier.php:1)

Here is my OnClick Function (From echo of an AJAX):

```
<button onclick="AddMenuOnTable(\''.$row['kode_menu'].'\',\''.$row['harga_jual'].'\')" class="btn btn-success">+</button>
```

And this is my script:

```
function AddMenuOnTable(kode,harga){
   var tableRef = document.getElementById('whatToOrder').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
   var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);
   var cell_jumlah = newRow.insertCell(3);
   var newText = String(harga);
   cell_jumlah.className = "harga";
   cell_jumlah.appendChild(newText);
}
```

From the code above, i'm trying to add a data to the table but it always return an error
I'm sorry for my bad english, im new on web development

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating `cell` and then uses `appendChild()`. so instead `appendChild()` you can try:

```
cell_jumlah.innerHTML = newText;
```